# RAS server low performance to a single host

Tags: rras

I have built up a solution using Microsoft's Always-On VPN. The basics of the configuration is as follows:

2x VMs running Server 2019 with latest updates 2x Network adapters, 1 in "internal" network and 1 in "external" network Default route on external network, static routes added in RAS console to route RFC1918 addresses to "internal" gateway

For the most part the solution works well but i have a performance reported with a line of buisness application (SAP R3)

Through process of elimination i've basically boiled the problem down to the performance between the RAS server and the SAP server being poor. In order to identify this I initially tested running the same operation in SAP and used a stopwatch, but i've actually managed to use the Siege HTTP testing tool to do a bit more easy testing without having to install the application to different places, log in, etc

The traffic from the VPN server to the SAP server goes across a site to site VPN (Cisco FlexVPN IKEv2), but that appears to be performing fine as the slow traffic appears to only come from one server, not the whole network

From the RAS server running the test command

siege SAP_SERVER_IP:8020 -b --time=60S

Transactions: 935 hits Availability: 100.00 % Elapsed time: 6.55 secs Data transferred: 18.07 MB Response time: 0.06 secs Transaction rate: 142.81 trans/sec Throughput: 2.76 MB/sec Concurrency: 9.28 Successful transactions: 950 Failed transactions: 0 Longest transaction: 3.06 Shortest transaction: 0.00

And from another server in the same source subnet is many many times faster:

Transactions: 36716 hits Availability: 100.00 % Elapsed time: 59.80 secs Data transferred: 76.00 MB Response time: 0.02 secs Transaction rate: 614.00 trans/sec Throughput: 1.27 MB/sec Concurrency: 12.23 Successful transactions: 0 Failed transactions: 0 Longest transaction: 3.06 Shortest transaction: 0.00

However, where it gets weird, I ran a test to another web server (in the same subnet as the destination SAP server) and got the following results:

Transactions: 8172 hits Availability: 100.00 % Elapsed time: 59.23 secs Data transferred: 155.40 MB Response time: 0.06 secs Transaction rate: 137.98 trans/sec Throughput: 2.62 MB/sec Concurrency: 8.56 Successful transactions: 8172 /Failed transactions: 0 Longest transaction: 3.27 Shortest transaction: 0.00

And from the "working" server I tested from in the previous results (testing against the SAP Server)

Transactions: 7708 hits Availability: 100.00 % Elapsed time: 59.10 secs Data transferred: 146.58 MB Response time: 0.10 secs Transaction rate: 130.43 trans/sec Throughput: 2.48 MB/sec Concurrency: 13.53 Successful transactions: 7708 Failed transactions: 0 Longest transaction: 3.48 Shortest transaction: 0.00

Basically performance is roughly the same (within margin of error at least)

I opened wireshark to try to see the differences between the tests,

The following test for the fast server, I noticed the MSS value was 1460 on the "outgoing" packet and then 1300 on the "incoming" packet

5176 2020-05-07 16:50:00.461214 RAS_SERVER_IP FAST_WEB_SERVER_IP TCP 66 64439 → 80 [SYN, ECN, CWR] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1 5238 2020-05-07 16:50:00.462856 FAST_WEB_SERVER_IP RAS_SERVER_IP TCP 66 80 → 64425 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1300 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

For the slow SAP server it looks as follows:

245 2020-05-07 16:53:21.554203 RAS_SERVER_IP SAP_SERVER_IP TCP 66 52481 → 8020 [SYN, ECN, CWR] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1 249 2020-05-07 16:53:21.554617 SAP_SERVER_IP RAS_SERVER_IP TCP 62 8020 → 52479 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1300 WS=2

but I noticed after I get a load of retransmissions: 14005 2020-05-07 17:08:13.576985 SAP_SERVER_IP RAS_SERVER_IP TCP 1354 [TCP Retransmission] 8020 → 64806 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=150 Win=66300 Len=1300

I ran the same test on the server that gave good performance and it mostly looked the same but I didnt see the restransmissions

tl;dr = Traffic from a RAS server to a particular server is slow, from another source server in the same network fast, and to another destination server from the slow source server its also fast ..

Does anyone have any idea where I can look to try to solve this? I'm really out of ideas :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found that the "Enable MAC address spoofing" option was turned on for the Internal NIC of the Hyper-V Virtual Machine, when it was only required for the external NIC (where Network Load Balacing is running).

I switched this off and it fixed the performance problem.